# Morphophonemic rules in phonology

Tags: phonology, morphology, phonemes, allophones, phones

I am wondering how the two phonological terms "morphonemic rules" and "morphophonemic rules" can be distinguished? 
A morpheme might have different presentations (i.e. pronunciations) and as far as I know, **morphonemic rules** are utilized in order to specify different phones (pronunciations / realizations) of that particular phoneme. 
**Example:**

> The plural /s/ sounds [z], whenever a noun ends in anything else than <+sibilants> or <-voice> segments.

According to what we were taught at the university, this is considered to be a **morphonemic rule**, but what are **morphophonemic rules**?

Comment: I think these are just different names for the same thing, one a simple compound, the other a reduced portmanteau by haplology

Comment: Thank you very much for the response, just may I ask you to provide me with a source link @Tristan?

Comment: I don't have one (which is part of why this is a comment not an answer). I will note that the wikipedia page for morphophonology begins by saying "(also morphophonemics or morphonology)" though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that these are just variant pronunciations (and spellings). The overwhelmingly standard term is *morphophonemic*. The haplological alternative arose in the late 60's and 70's but subsided in frequency. Perhaps some day someone will undertake an in-depth study of these terms in the literature, but no such study has been undertaken, thus you have to rely on intuitions of phonologists who have been reading phonology over a long period of time. It should be noted that either term is archaic and does not correspond to any generally-accepted theoretical concept of modern phonology.

As a poor substitute, you can inspect the Google Ngram of those terms, and you will see that *morphophonemic* is 100-fold more frequent than *morphonemic*. The Ngram viewer will also lead you to historical instances of usage, where you can try to get the meaning from context.

Comment: To sum it up, they mean the same and "morphophonemic" precedes historically the term "morphonemic". Agreed?

Comment: Yes, that is it.